# Weird output with cout.precision() in c++

Tags: c++

My code is a very simple e number calculation method. It works without problems.

```
#include <iostream>

double e (unsigned int n){
    double result, product;
    result = 1;
    product = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        product *= i;
        result += 1/product;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    unsigned int n;
    std::cout << "e number" << "\n";
    std::cout << "Iteration count = ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n << " iterations => e = " << 
    e(n) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
e number 
Iteration count = 2 
2 iterations => e = 2.5

e number    
Iteration count = 5
5 iterations => e = 2.71667

e number
Iteration count = 225
2225 iterations => e = 2.71828
```

The problem is that when I tried to show much more decimals, for example 15, with the following code,
    std::cout.precision(15) << e(n) << "\n";
instead of

```
e(n) << "\n";
```

the output changes to

```
e number
Iteration count = 2
2 iterations => e = 62.5
e number
Iteration count = 5
5 iterations => e = 62.71666666666667
e number
Iteration count = 225
225 iterations => e = 62.71828182845905
```

Why is there a '6' outputted before the e value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) is a function that both sets the specified decimal precision, and returns the previous precision on the stream object.  So, the previous precision is `6` before your code changed it to 15.  And since you inlined the call into the print operation, `6` is getting fed to the output stream.

Just call `setprecision` outside of the print statement.

```
std::cout.setprecision(15);
std::cout << n << " iterations => e = " << e(n) << std::endl;
```